# Finding Probability of a digit given a sequences?

Tags: probability, forecasting, predictive-models, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I have a n sequences of numbers ranges from 1 to 4, say sequence s1 = [1,3, 1, 4] and s2 = [**2**,1,3,4] up to s(n).

My question is how can i find probability of a number coming right after a sequence, from above data i want to know Pr(2 given sequence s1) 2 is the first observation from next sequence and so on.

Should i use state space models like Markov decision process or hidden markov model.